# How do you get a parallel vector on a plane that an intersecting ray just hit?

Tags: html, math, three.js, webgl, shader

My problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5g5M.jpg

What I have: **intersect, n, p**. Where p is a random point in the space. N is the plane's normal.

What I seek: **w**

How I tried to solve it in my shader:

```
"vec3 n = normalize(faceNormal);",
"vec3 p = vec3(1.0);",
"vec3 u = p - intersect;",
"vec3 absNormal = abs(n);",
"vec3 v = dot(u, n) * n / (absNormal * absNormal);",
"vec3 w = u - v;",
```

And the vector doesn't become parallel with the plane: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSvsw.png

Anybody see where I've thought wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`abs()` is the absolute value. You should be using the `length()` function.

```
"vec3 v = dot( u, n ) * n / ( length( n ) * length( n ) );",
```

Comment: Ah, thanks West Langley, works now. I thought they were the same thing.